# How do I change the max failed login attempts to lock out the user in Weblogic 10.0?

Tags: weblogic, login-attempts, lockout

We have a requirement to set the number of login attempts to 3 before we lock out the user. It seems the default is 5. How do I change this value in Weblogic 10.0?

Answer (score 1):

Log into the WLS console and go to:
  Home >  Summary of Security Realms >  myrealm  > Configuration > User Lockout

There the Lockout Threshold is the times a user may attempt a login before locking.

Comment: how do I do this if I can't access the console?